# Error: ExchangeImpersonation SOAP header must be present for this type of oauth token

Tags: oauth-2.0, exchangewebservices

I am trying to use Exchange Web Services (EWS) with application and OAuth2 authentication.

What I did:

- registered on Azure portal application, granted all required permissions (even `full_access_as_app` for Exchange); accepted these permissions as an admin;
- prepared correct OAuth2 Bearer token (with scope `https://outlook.office365.com/.default`);
- prepared SOAP request with SOAP UI. As basis for this request I use this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getattachment-operation . Additionally I've added HTTP Authorization header with Bearer token, X-AnchorMailbox with target mailbox.

As a result I get this one: "ExchangeImpersonation SOAP header must be present for this type of OAuth token". I cannot understand what should I do to fix it.

Even tried with ExchangeImpersonate and SmtpAddress with the same mailbox address as above but in this way I get another error "Mailbox not found". But mailbox is! (tested on several mailboxes).

My questions is: what am I doing wrong with EWS?

Request:

```
POST https://outlook.office365.com/ews/Exchange.asmx
Authorization: Bearer <token>
X-AnchorMailbox: mailbox@something.onmicrosoft.com


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2016"/>
        <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
            <t:ConnectingSID>
                <t:PrimarySmtpAddress>
                    mailbox@something.onmicrosoft.com
                </t:PrimarySmtpAddress>
            </t:ConnectingSID>
        </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetAttachment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
    xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <AttachmentShape/>
      <AttachmentIds>
        <t:AttachmentId Id="AAMkADAwNzdjNTg3LTc4M2ItNDE0Yi05MTk4LTQxZDBlYTc1NmMxZgBGAAAAAAAiixtLGariQY7rf5pAKRZZBwBVk8babsuEQ4s2Znfj9fB5AAAAAAEMAABVk8babsuEQ4s2Znfj9fB5AADq3B14AAABEgAQAKZOAcjZCBxHpqvY6XmXp5w="/>
      </AttachmentIds>
    </GetAttachment>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
ErrorNonExistentMailbox The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it.
```

Comment: Have you tried using Basic auth just to validate everything in the request is okay and your permission are correct. That would at least allow you to be able to pinpoint is it oAuth causing the issue or your request. You should always post the request or a code sample with your question which help people looking at it

Comment: Yes, I've tried Basic auth and everything works fine

Comment: The next thing would be to check the token your using, for impersonation you should be using the delegate grant (not the application permission). An easy way to test that is use the EWSEditor https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor/releases its supports both using oAuth (via it on app reg) and use Impersonation. If this works that should narrow it down to the application registration or the way you generating the token. You can also check the token grants using https://jwt.io/

Comment: Problem is solved. Simply wrong SOAP fomatting was used in client.

Comment: @zamazan4ik, can you please elaborate how did you add the soap header to the request? I am trying to do the same thing and stuck with the same issue. Your response will really help.

Answer (score 9):

This fixed it for me.

```
_exchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId = 
    new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, userEmailAddress);
```

Comment: More context would make this a better answer! Where do you put this code?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to instantiate impersonation as below:

```
var ews = new Rebex.net.Ews();
ews.Connect(outlook.office365.com);
ews.Settings.Impersonation = new EwsImpersonation();
ews.Settings.Impersonation.SmtpAddress = <mailbox address>;
```

Comment: Your example is using a commercial product so it isnt much help for those without that.